# Showing any XML or JS Object as a Tree

Tags: javascript, xml, treeview

I know there are lots of libraries which creates Tree View Component. But every one of them expects a pre-defined structure. I want something which would take any XML or a JS object and show it as a Tree View. Very much like Firebug/Safari Developer shows it for any JS object or any browser esp. IE showing for an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Online you can show it at : http://view.xmlgrid.net/

In C#, you can write some code to generate it dynamically : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597

Answer (score 1):

I have also written online tools that accomplish this.  Try my [JSON viewer](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/) and [XML beautifier](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could give the dojo tree view a shot. I just skimmed through the documentation and it looks like the structure of the tree is pulled out of a datastore like the data itself. Also (not sure though) I think there is a data store wich can read and write XML and with a bit of tweaking could be used to provide data to the tree view.

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Tree?highlight=%28Tree%29

edit: 
After reading the documentation of the tree for a bit it seems that using the tree models you can dynamicly modify the tree. And there appears to be a data store which can read xml data (dojox.data.XmlStore).

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic tree view of JSON, try [Online JSON Tree Viewer Tool](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/online-json-tree-viewer)